# How to use Scala Stack for a postfix arithmetic calculation?

Tags: scala, stack, rdd

I wrote an algorithm to get an infix statement change it to postfix and now I want to perform the calculation on that statement. I have seen [this as a sample](https://github.com/bitwalker/RPNCalculator/blob/master/src/main/scala/App.scala) but I cannot understand what happens in some parts of it. It is using Scala Stack.

1. How does this part work:

   ```
    case x :: y :: xs => xs ++ List(op(y, x))
   ```
2. The types that I am using in my calculations are integer numbers and RDDs so in this example if I replace the "Float" with "Any" is that right?

Comment: If you don't understand what that line is doing, I suspect you don't understand what scala's `match` statement does at all.  Check out a tutorial like http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_pattern_matching.htm then come back to it.

Comment: @soong thanks I understand the match my problem is the syntax "x::y::xs "

Comment: The `::` is a syntax special to the `List` that symbolizes appending to the list. So, the overall thing there is 'Can I deconstruct this as a list with two items and a remainder (which can be empty)? If so, those items are `x` and `y`, and the remainder is `xs`'

Comment: Thank you Soong that was my answer to the first question!

Comment: In regards to part 2, I'm not too familiar with RDDs, but from looking at the API, I'm a little confused. Are they of type `RDD[Int]`? Do `RDD` objects have the basic arithmetic operations?  I don't see them, but maybe I'm not looking for an implicit conversion somewhere that's relevant.

Comment: So based on this: "++, returns a new collection containing the elements from the left operand followed by the elements from the right operand", it performs "op" on "y" and "x" and the "xs" as the result of the calculation and returns all as a list of Float back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move my comment into an answer and then attempt to answer part 2:

The `::` is a special syntax with `List` (as well as other collections) that represents prepending to an existing list.  The pattern in question (within the context of the encompassing `match`) is to match a list with two elements (which will be stored in `x` and `y`, respectively) and a remainder (which can be empty or `Nil` and is stored in `xs`).

As for the second question, I'm a little confused as to how exactly you're going to parse an item to an RDD, but I would recommend that you make a type of token class that can encapsulate either an integer or an RDD.  This way, you can't have any errors down the road where something tries to pass in a completely unrelated value because you declared it as `Any`.

Edit: based on your comment, I would recommend something like this:

```
expressions match {
    case x: RDD :: y: RDD :: xs => {//do what you want with two RDDs here}
    case x: RDD :: y: Int :: xs => {//do what you want with one of each here}
    case x: Int :: y: RDD :: xs => {//do what you want with one of each in the other order here}
    case x: Int :: y: Int :: xs => {//do what you want with two Ints here}
}
```

Comment: I have implemented "+ - / *" for RDD calculation and my RDDs are : RDD[(Int,Array[Float])] now what I need to do is that by the time I am checking whether there are two items in the list to perform the operation and whether they are an RDD and a float, RDD and RDD, or Float and Float, then call my override + - * / for them and push back the results into the stack

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you so much it's a good hint and gave me an idea how to deal with it!

Comment: I have another question (sort of syntax again) in that program I can create a new question if you think it's needed. I was wondering about the "op" in expr and reduce function how does it work , where does it get the current operator?

Comment: That's an implicit function coming from scala.util.parsing.combinator.ImplicitConversions.scala.  You can find more about them at http://bitwalker.org/blog/2013/08/10/learn-by-example-scala-parser-combinators/